# Find the filename that launched your OS X app

Tags: macos, launch-services

Setting the info of a file you can associate an app with a particular file type so that when clicked the application is launched.
My question is how the app can discover the full filename of the file that caused it to be launched.

Comment: What language are you working in? Is this Cocoa app, or something more unusual? Also, which version of macOS do you need to support?

Comment: I am using GNAT Ada on Mojave so I suppose it is based on Cocoa.

Comment: So far I have had little recourse to access OSX specific features although I call _NSGetExecutablePath to get the full filename of the app.
I am hoping that there is a similar call that will return the name of the launch file.

Answer (score 3):

Mac apps are not launched every time an associated file is opened. They may be launched, but if they're already running, then they're just asked to open another file. So the path doesn't come to the app via the commandline. It's sent as a message to the application, which needs to process a run loop (NSRunLoop) to receive it.

In a regular Cocoa program, you implement an NSApplicationDelegate, and implement the method (in ObjC naming):

```
- (BOOL)application:(NSApplication *)sender openFile:(NSString *)filename;
```

If you only support 10.13+, the preferred method has changed to:

```
- (void)application:(NSApplication *)application openURLs:(NSArray<NSURL *> *)urls;
```

The OS will call this when your application needs to open a file if there's an NSApplication object running to accept it. Typically you create an NSApplication object by calling `NSApplicationMain()`, but you can implement your own version of `NSApplicationMain()` if you need to (see the [NSApplication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication?language=objc#) docs for details).

It is possible to respond to these open requests without an NSApplication, or any Objective-C, by implementing Apple Events yourself and responding to the `odoc` (open document; `{ kCoreEventClass, kAEOpenDocuments }`) message. To attack that, see [The Apple Events Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleEvents/responding_aepg/responding_aepg.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001449-CH206-BEJBDEGI).

You should expect to write some piece of code that installs an event handler like:

```
err     = AEInstallEventHandler(kCoreEventClass, kAEOpenDocuments,
            NewAEEventHandlerUPP(OpenDocumentsAE), 0, false);
require_noerr(err, CantInstallAppleEventHandler);
```

And then you would actually handle the message in `OpenDocumentsAE` (taken from "A Handler for the Open Documents Apple Event"):

```
static pascal OSErr OpenDocumentsAE(const AppleEvent *theAppleEvent, AppleEvent *reply, long handlerRefcon)
{
    AEDescList  docList;
    FSRef       theFSRef;
    long        index;
    long        count = 0;
    OSErr       err = AEGetParamDesc(theAppleEvent,
                            keyDirectObject, typeAEList, &docList);// 1
    require_noerr(err, CantGetDocList);// 2

    err = AECountItems(&docList, &count);// 3
    require_noerr(err, CantGetCount);

    for(index = 1; index <= count; index++)// 4
    {
        err = AEGetNthPtr(&docList, index, typeFSRef,
                        NULL, NULL, &theFSRef, sizeof(FSRef), NULL);// 5
        require_noerr(err, CantGetDocDescPtr);

        err = OpenDocument(&theFSRef);// 6
    }
    AEDisposeDesc(&docList);// 7

CantGetDocList:
CantGetCount:
CantGetDocDescPtr:
    if (err != noErr)// 8
    {
        // For handlers that expect a reply, add error information here.
    }
    return(err);// 9
}
```

Comment: Dear Rob,
Thank you for your reply.
Some of my applications use Gtk.
I assume that in order to function Gtk will create and handle the main NsApplication loop. If the application is launched from an associated file, then my understanding (now) is that the application is started and then sent an event that it needs to open the file. However isn't there a race condition here? If I create a delegate to handle the event isn't there a chance that I will miss the event?

Comment: No; messages will queue until they are consumed by the application object. When you see an app "beachball" that means that the OS has sent messages to the app that it has not consumed for at least 500ms. But they still generally queue up.